# Why doesn't the variable exist (aspx)?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This is a .aspx file (web form) in an asp.net project (.net 4.7.2).

The local variable `myTestString` is defined at line 3. Why does it say that it doesn't exist at line 14?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to define your variable in a `<script runat="server">...</script>` block rather than a `<% ... %>` block, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/f0111sbh(v=vs.100). Alternatively, you can declare it as a protected property in your code-behind `.aspx.cs` file.

Comment: I see the problem now. It seems that it is the `runat="server"` on the form element. When using the variable outside the form element it is working.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the variable is being used inside an element with `runat="server"`.